# Beeswax for lubricating hinges. How does it compare to other lubricants?

Tags: lubrication

As per title. I've recently discovered the amazing properties of beeswax and its multiplicity of uses from rust prevention, to food preservation, to lubricating/threadlocking wood screws.

https://matteroftrust.org/101-uses-for-beeswax/

It's also non-toxic with an agreeable odor compared to other lubricants.

Aside from cost and availability, are there any disadvantages, contraindications or cautions to using natural beeswax for lubricating door hinges? Does anyone have useful practical experience?

Comment: I use wax on ropes that have weights to pull gates closed both natural rope and synthetic rope last longer with wax.

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotally, I waxed (my default, on the belief that it stays put and works which prior experience had born out) a squeaky door hinge last year, and it quieted down for a short time, then resumed squeaking.

When I addressed it the next time, I used petroleum jelly - due to what I had handy, specifically the mentholated version (Vick's Vapo-Rub, no endorsement implied) and it has remained quiet since (which is a longer period of time than the wax worked for.)

Comment: And it kept your nose cleared up, just by walking through the doorway! :):)